# User has made in-app purchase on iOS and has sent us the payment screenshot. But how do we check if payment was made?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

On our app in iOS, whenever a user makes payment through in-app purchase, we receive receipt from storekit and that helps us authenticate a payment.

However, a few users have emailed us screenshots of email from apple showing they have made payment for in-app purchase for our iOS app. But, we are unable to trace the in-app purchase receipt. Now since we only have the user's email adrress / screenshot of email and order ID, how do we track this in-app purchase?

Comment: You can't. Is it a consumable or non-consumable purchase?  Does you code correctly ensure that the purchase is persisted before marking the transaction as complete?

Comment: Also, do you check for incomplete transactions when the app launches?

Comment: @paulw11 It is a Auto-Renewable Subscription. Yes in our code the purchase is persisted before making the transaction and also we are checking the incomplete transaction when the app launches.

Comment: If you are properly persisting the purchase before marking the transaction complete, then the situation you describe shouldn't arise.  Even if it does, all the user should need to do is use the restore button in your app to restore their in-app purchase. Your app should also be checking the receipt each time it starts in order to detect subscription renewal

Comment: @paulw11 In our app after the complete transaction we are upgrading the user and auto restoring the in-app purchase instead of giving the button to restore. And also, we are checking the receipt in back-end for auto renewal subscription.

Comment: When do you perform the auto restore?  Only on a successful purchase? It sounds like the simple addition of a manual restore button might fix your issue.  It sounds like if the original subscription receipt doesn't get to your server then you won't have a receipt to check renewal